# Ionic View with Ionic 2 app

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2, ionic-view

I know the Ionic View does not support all Cordova plugins (http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage).

I have an app that is working in Chrome and on Android device.

When trying the same app with Ionic View with my Android device, it seems the http requests are not returning anything.

I don't see whitlist support, so do you think it could be the cause of my issue?

If so, is there a way to make it work?

Any plan, by Ionic team, to add that cordova plugin support?

[UPDATE]

Here is my AndroidManifesst.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/share_name" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you have add `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />` ? ref: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist

Comment: what about INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @PeacePan, I do have what you said in my config.xml, but with https in my case

Comment: @wisdom, I updated my post with the AndroidManifest.xml. It is the one that was automatically generated. Should I add what Peace Pan suggested or do you see something that I should try to add?

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you are using to make a http request.

Comment: @BenSmith, I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but here an example: this._http.request(url).map((res: Response) => res.json()); Thanks